# Difficulties in solving a PDE problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

This is an exercise in ["Variation et optimisation des formes"](http://ebookee.org/Variation-et-optimisation-de-formes-Une-analyse-g-om-trique-By-Antoine-Henrot-Michel-Pierre_306986.html), chapter 3, Ex. 3.8. The preliminaries are:
$$D=(0,1)^2,\ f \in L^2(D),\ x_{ij}=(i/n, j/n),\ 0<i,j<n,$$
$$\Omega_n = D\setminus \bigcup_{0<i,j<n} \overline{B}(x_{ij},r_n), u_n=u_{\Omega_n}^f.$$

We pick $r_n=e^{-dn^2}$.

The notation $u_\Omega^f$ is the unique solution of the problem $-\Delta u=f$, which means 
$$ \int_\Omega fv=\int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla v,\ \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega).$$

> 1) Prove that there exists $u^* \in H_0^1(D)$ and a subsequence of $u_n$ which converges weakly in $H_0^1(D)$ to $u^*$ and strongly in $L^2(D)$ to the same function.

This is not very hard, and there are some theorems in the book which help.

> 2) This is the part where it becomes messy. Consider the squares centred at $x_{ij}$ with sides $1/n$. Consider further the circles inscribed in these squares and denote with $C_{ij}^n$ the annulus formed by the inscribed circle in the square (centred in $x_{ij}$ with radius $1/2n$) and the circle of center $x_{ij}$ and radius $r_n$.
>
> Define the following functions $z_n \in H^1(D)$ with the properties

- $\Delta z_n=0$ on $C_{ij}^n$;
- $z_n=0$ on $B(x_{ij},r_n)$;
- $z_n=1$ elsewhere.

> Determine the expression of $z_n$ for each small square (cell)[I managed to do this assuming that the solutions are radially constant around $x_{ij}$]. Here comes the part I can't get:
>
> **Prove that for each small square $-\Delta z_n=\mu_n-\nu_n$ where $\mu_n,\nu_n$ are the positive measures with support respectively the circles $C(x_{ij},1/2n)$ and $C(x_{ij},r_n)$.**

The problem has more parts, but to get there I need to understand this one. Thank you.

[edit:] To clarify the aspects in Florian's comment: I don't understand why $-\Delta z_n$ has the given formula, and don't know how the measures $\mu_n,\nu_n$ are defined. In my intuition, $-\Delta z_n=0$ since this is the condition on $C_{ij}^n$ and outside this annulus $z_n$ is constant.

Comment: Are you asking what it means that a differential operator applied to a function is a measure, or do you know that and you just can't do it? Or in other words, is your question about terminology or about calculations?

Comment: @Florian: My question is mostly about terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to know what distributions and distributional derivatives are. It's best to look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29).

The important points are: Distributions are continuous functionals on a space of test functions (usually $C_c ^\infty(\Omega)$ for some domain $\Omega$, that is, smooth functions with compact support inside $\Omega$). A function $u$ (which has to be at least in $L_{\rm loc}^1$) is identified with the distribution $\varphi \mapsto \int_\Omega u \varphi$. More generally, a Radon measure $\mu$ is identified with the distribution $\varphi\mapsto \int \varphi d \mu$.

Any distribution can be differentiated: if $T$ is a distribution and $s\in \{1,...,n\}$ and $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ then $\partial_s T(\varphi):=-T(\partial_s \varphi)$. Thus $\Delta T(\varphi)=T(\Delta \varphi)$. This makes it possible to differentiate any function; the derivatives might be functions or measures (that is, distributions which can be identified with a function or a measure) but in general they are not.

When you are asked to show that $\Delta z = \mu - \nu$ with measures $\mu,\nu$, this has to be interpreted in the distributional sense explained above. Unwrapping all definitions, you have to show that there exist positive Radon measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that for all $\varphi\in C_c ^\infty(\Omega)$,
$$\int_\Omega z \Delta \varphi = \int \varphi d \mu - \int \varphi d \nu$$
and since you have an explicit formula for $z$, you can work this out (Hint: Gauss theorem or Green's identities might help).

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. :)