# understanding of the classical definition of Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I learn the classical definition of Green's function from Hunter's *[Applied Analysis](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/pdfbook.html)*.

Consider the second-order ordinary differential operators $A$ of the form 
$$Au=au''+bu'+cu,$$
where $a,b$ and $c$ are sufficiently smooth functions on $[0,1]$.

Think about the Dirichlet boundary value problem for the second-order differential operator $A$ defined above:
$$Au=f,\qquad u(0)=u(1)=0,\qquad \tag{10.9}$$
where $f:[0,1]\to{\mathbb C}$ is a given continuous function.

The author gives a heuristic discussion using Dirac delta function:
the Green's function $g(x,y)$ associated with the boundary value problem in (10.9) is the solution of the following problem:
$$Ag(x,y)=\delta(x-y),\qquad g(0,y)=g(1,y)=0.\qquad \tag{10.13}$$
He reformulates $(10.13)$ in classical, pointwise terms. The book said that we want $g(x,y)$ to satisfy the homogeneous ODE(as a function of $x$) when $x\neq y$, and **we want the jump in $a(x)g_x(x,y)$ across $x=y$ to equal one in order to obtain a delta function after taking a second $x$-derivative**. We therefore make the following definition:†

---

> † A function $g:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to{\mathbb C}$ is a Green's function for (10.9) if it satisfies the following conditions.
>
> (a) The function $g(x,y)$ is continuous on the square $0\leq x,y\leq 1$, and twice continuously differentiable with respect to $x$ on the triangles $0\leq x\leq y\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1$, meaning that the partial derivatives exist in the interiors of the triangles and extend to continuous functions on the closures. The left and right limits of the partial derivatives on $x=y$ are not equal, however.
>
> (b) The function $g(x,y)$ satisfies the ODE with respect to $x$ and the boundary conditions:
>   $$\begin{align}
> Ag=0\qquad \text{in}~0<x<y<1~\text{and}~0<y<x<1,\\
> g(0,y)=g(1,y)=0\qquad\text{for}~0\leq y\leq 1.
> \end{align}
> $$
>   **(c)** The jump in $g_x$ across the line $x=y$ is given by
>   $$g_x(y^+,y)-g_x(y^-,y)=\frac{1}{a(y)}$$
>   where the subscript $x$ denotes a partial derivative with respect to the first variable in $g(x,y)$, and 
>   $$g_x(y^+,y)=\lim_{x\to y^+}g_x(x,y),\qquad g_x(y^-,y)=\lim_{x\to y^-}g_x(x,y).$$

---

The words in bold---

**...we want the jump in $a(x)g_x(x,y)$ across $x=y$ to equal one in order to obtain a delta function after taking a second $x$-derivative**

refer to condition (c) in the definition above.

Here is my question:

How can one get 
$Ag(x,y)=\delta(x-y)$
from
$$g_x(y^+,y)-g_x(y^-,y)=\frac{1}{a(y)}?$$
**Added**:

The confusion is that I don't know what the words in bold mean. Finally, we want $$Ag(x,y)=\delta(x-y),$$ but what's the relation between "taking a second $x$-derivative" of $a(x)g_x(x,y)$ and $Ag(x,y)$?

Comment: The definition doesn't discuss properties of the function $a(y)$.   As long as $a(y)$ is sufficiently nice then it seems possible to define the jump to be 1.  Perhaps I am missing something in your question.

Comment: @Alice: No, it doesn't. It only mentioned that $a$ is sufficiently smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:(a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:[b,c)\to\mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$-functions. The derivative of $F:(a,c)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$F(x):=\begin{cases}f(x) & x<b \cr g(x) & x>b\end{cases}$$
equals $\tilde F + (g(b)-f(b))\delta_b$ where $\tilde F$ is the classical derivative
$$\tilde F(x):=\begin{cases}f'(x) & x<b \cr g'(x) & x>b\end{cases}$$
in the [distributional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) sense. In other words, if a function has a jump, then its derivative is a delta distribution which measures the height of the jump (in addition to the classical derivative).

See also [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51212/difficulties-in-solving-a-pde-problem/51441#51441) to get a very quick overview on distributions, and what it means for a function to have a distribution or a measure as its derivative (note that the delta distribution is actually a measure).

**Edit**: Here is a heuristic reason of why this is true. The function $F$ is defined piecewise by $f$ on the left side of $b$ and $g$ on the right side of $b$ (the value at $b$ precisely is not important, you can think of the function as a graph which has a vertical line at $b$), but the two pieces don't fit together at $b$. What could the derivative of $F$ reasonably be? If you just ignore the discontinuity at $b$ and differentiate $f$ and $g$ seperately, you get $\tilde F$, but you see that it's not a good candidate for a derivative as soon as you test the fundamental theorem of calculus: Let $x\in (a,b)$ and $y\in (b,c)$, then
$$\int_x ^y \tilde F(t) dt=\int_x ^b f'(t) dt + \int_b ^y g'(t) dt=f(b)-f(x)+g(y)-g(b)$$
where it should be $g(y)-f(x)$. So we are off by $g(b)-f(b)$ which is the height of the jump, so we correct it by adding this number times $\delta_b$ to it. $\delta_b$ has the property that it's zero outside of $b$, and
$$\int_x ^y \delta_b(t)=1$$
Of course such a function does not exist, that's why it's heuristic. Making this rigorous requires the theory of distributions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Question has been edited. I don't quite follow your answer.

Comment: You apply this result to $F:=g_x$ (restricted to a fixed $y$), my $f$ and $g$ are your $g_x$ defined in the two triangles, extended continuously to the diagonal, and restricted to a fixed $y$. If you are confused by the definition of distributions, you can still consider this result as heuristically true.

Comment: I don't understand the $F$ in the answer. It is from $(a,c)$ to ${\mathbb R}$. But in your definition of $F$, it is NOT defined at $x=b$.

Comment: Also, I don't understand "the derivative of $F$". Do you mean the derivative of $F$ in the interval $(a,c)$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that, *by definition*, we require continuity of the Green's function at $x=y$.

Consider the ODE involving our Green's function,

$$A[g] = a_2(x)\frac{\mathrm d^2 g(x,y)}{\mathrm{dx}^2}+a_1(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}g(x,y)}{\mathrm{dx}} + a_0(x)g(x,y) = \mathrm{\delta}(x-y)\ .$$

We now integrate the equation around the point of continuity $x=y$ of $g$ by taking the following limit
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{x = y-\varepsilon}^{y+\varepsilon}A[g]\ dx = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{y-\varepsilon}^{y+\varepsilon}\mathrm{\delta}(x-y)\ dx \ .$$

The right hand side evaluates to $1$.

On the left hand side, everything vanishes except the second derivative term. (You can check this by using integration by parts and exploiting the fact that $g$ is continuous).

That being said, using integration by parts, we can write

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\ a_2(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}g(x,y)}{\mathrm{dx}} \Bigg|_{x=y-\epsilon}^{y+\varepsilon}-\int_{y-\varepsilon}^{y+\varepsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}a_2(x)}{\mathrm{dx}}\frac{\mathrm{d}g(x,y)}{\mathrm{dx}}dx = 1\ .$$
Again, by using integration by parts, you can show that the second term vanishes because $g$ is continuous in $x=y$.

Hence, we now arrive at the "jump condition",

$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\ a_2(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}g(x,y)}{\mathrm{dx}} \Bigg|_{x=y-\epsilon}^{y+\varepsilon}  = 1\ .$$

Upon taking the limit, we obtain your expression

$$g_x(y^+,y)-g_x(y^{-},y) = \frac{1}{a_2(x)}\ . $$